# Khan Noonien Singh and the Mirror Universe

Tags: star-trek, mirror-universe, khan-singh

One of the comments to this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53120/why-was-spock-logical-in-the-mirror-universe) note that the Point of Departure from the Prime universe occurred somewhat earlier than when Zefram Cochrane murdered the Vulcan who made first contact with Earth, noting in the ENT story *In a Mirror, Darkly* had footage of an astronaut placing a mirror-universe-Earth (Earth with sword) on the Moon.

If so, has there been any stories involving or mentioning Khan Noonien Singh and the Eugenic Wars of the 1990's? Presumably Singh and his followers would have been seen just as much a threat the Terran Empire and the assumed Governments in the Prime Universe.

Comment: he's mentioned here: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Mirror and here: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sorrows_of_Empire but neither are really Khan stories